# Trying to create a stack in cloud formation using SAM and getting an error message

Tags: amazon-web-services, yaml, aws-cloudformation, aws-sam

When I am trying to deploy a stack using SAM I am getting the following error message.

"Failed to create changeset for the stack: test, ex: Waiter ChangeSetCreateComplete failed: Waiter encountered a terminal failure state: For expression "Status" we matched expected path: "FAILED" Status: FAILED. Reason: Invalid template resource property 'KeySchema'"

I am trying to create an API gateway that is connected to a Lambda function that would interact with a DynamoDB table. my YAML template file is valid and KeySchema seems to be a valid resource property according to documentation https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/quickref-dynamodb.html

My Yaml file looks like this

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Transform: AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31
Description: "Stack for DynamoDB, Lambda and APIGateway"
Resources:
  CounterFunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      CodeUri: Backend/
      Handler: lambda.lambda_handler
      Runtime: python3.8
        
      Events:
        VisitorData:
          Type: Api
          Properties:
           Path: /Counter
           Method: get
    
  Visitors:
    Type: AWS::DyanmoDB::Table
    Properties:
      AttributeDefinitions:
          -
            AttributeName: "ID"
            AttributeType: "N"
          -
            AttributeName: "Counter"
            AttributeType: "N"
      KeySchema:
        - AttributeName: "ID"
          KeyType: "HASH"
                
      ProvisionedThroughput:
            ReadCapacityUnits: 5
            WriteCapacityUnits: 5

Outputs:
  VisitorDataApi:
    Description: "API Gateway endpoint URL for Prod stage for Counter Function"
    Value: !Sub "https://${ServerlessRestApi}.execute-api.${AWS::Region}.amazonaws.com/Prod/hello/"
  CounterFunction:
    Description: "Counter Function lambda ARN"
    Value: !GetAtt CounterFunction.Arn
  HelloWorldFunctionIamRole:
    Description: "Implicit IAM Role created for Counter Function"
    Value: !GetAtt  Lambda-Get-Function-role-40isam1j
  Visitors Table:
    Description: "Visitor table ARN"
    Value: !GetAtt "Visitors.ARN"
```

I would appreciate any feedback and some insight to what the error message is trying to tell me thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It should be:

```
Type: AWS::DynamoDB::Table
```

not:

```
Type: AWS::DyanmoDB::Table
```

Comment: I switched it and rebuilt the files but the same error still pops up

Comment: @Noahharris you have to remove Counter from your attributes. The only attribute is ID. Nothing else in your case.

Comment: I get the same error regarding the key schema being an invalid resource property @Marcin

Comment: @Noahharris Can yo update your code. How does it look like now after the changes?

Answer (score 0):

I understand my mistakes in my code. @Marcin made some good points, but why nothing happened is due to the fact that it was making a new file called template.yml every time i built it. my original file name was Infrastructure.yml but the updates were created just in a new file thanks for your help